# Recommended Papers on GBM

Tags: machine-learning, references, boosting

I am writing my thesis and use a GBM to model insurance claim frequency. As I am currently writing the background, I am looking for good references on GBM. Do you have any recommendations for me? Any essential papers, that I should read/use as reference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of the following:

> Friedman, J. (2001). Greedy boosting approximation: a gradient
>   boosting machine. Ann. Stat. 29, 1189–1232. doi:
>   10.1214/aos/1013203451 [link](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/trebst.pdf)
>
> Friedman, J., Hastie, T., and Tibshirani, R. (2000). Additive logistic
>   regression: a statistical view of boosting. Ann. Stat. 28, 337–407.
>   doi: 10.1214/aos/1016218222 [link](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1016218223)
>
> J. H. Friedman. Stochastic gradient boosting. Computational Statistics
>   and Data Analysis, 38(4):367–378, 2002.  [link](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/stobst.pdf)

Friedman, Hastie, and Tibshirani (2000) paper discusses the first successful boosting algorithm, Adaboost from a statistical point of view. Friedman (2001) and the companion paper Friedman (2002) extended the work to generalize Adaboost to Gradient Boosting in order to handle a variety of loss functions.

There is a paper I came across but haven't had the chance to go in depth:

> (May 4) David Mease and Abraham Wyner (2008). Evidence contrary to the
>   statistical view of boosting. Journal of Machine Learning Research,
>   vol 9, pp 131--156 [link](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/mease08a/mease08a_with_discussion.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will definetly look into these!